# Model name visible in Admin section

Tags: python, django-models

I am using Python 3.10.0 and Django 3.2.9

I created a new app in my django project, and then created a model called Posts. Everything works as intended except for how it's name is being displayed in the admin section of the website. It says "Postss" (double s in the end).
If I change the model name to "Post" or just one letter "P" for instance, django automatically adds "s" to the end of it's name, so it is being displayed as "Posts" or "Ps" then.

Other words, whatever the model name is, django automatically adds "s" in the end of it's name in the admin pannel of the website.

Is it possible to tell django I don't want that "s" to be added? How?

[image: screenshot of code and admin pannel]

Thanks a mil, guys.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally models have *singular* names, so `Post`, not <s>`Posts`</s>. You thus might want to consider renaming your model.

If you still want to use `Posts` as model name, you can specify the *verbose* name of the model, and the plural verbose name with the [**`verbose_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) and the [**`verbose_name_plural`** model options [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) respectively:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'posts'
```

But as said before, if you rename your model `Post`, Django will convert the PerlCase to a name with spaces and as plural append the name with an `s`.